# Jquery for replace bullet unicode

Tags: jquery, html, regex

I am using following jQuery code to replace `[bullet/]` with its unicode character:

```
html = html.replace(/\[bullet/gi, '&bull;');
```

However it's not working. Does anyone know what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Two problems there:

1. `[` is a special character in regular expressions (it marks the beginning of a *character class*), so your regex is invalid (you should have been getting an error about this in the web console, telling you what was wrong). To literally match a `[`, you have to escape it:

   ```
   html = html.replace(/\[bullet/gi, '•');
   // Backslash here ---^
   ```
2. Separately, that will match `[bullet`, not `[bullet/]`. If you want to match the whole thing, you have to put the whole thing in:

   ```
   html = html.replace(/\[bullet\/\]/gi, '•');
   ```

   Note that like `[`, `/` is a special character (the delimiter), so you have to escape it as well. I also escaped `]`, but you don't really need to outside a character class.

This also works if you're using the entity:

```
html = html.replace(/\[bullet\/\]/gi, '&bull;');
```

Gratuitous example:

```js
var str;

str = "foo [bullet/] bar [bullet/] baz";
snippet.log("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace(/\[bullet\/\]/gi, '•');
snippet.log("After: " + str);

str = "foo [bullet/] bar [bullet/] baz";
snippet.log("Before: " + str);
str = str.replace(/\[bullet\/\]/gi, '&bull;');
snippet.log("After: " + str);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: @SSAT: Your question says you're trying to use `•`, not `&bull;`. But in any case, yes, it does (hit refresh, maybe #2 wasn't there).